# Realtime traffic data provider(s)

Tags: data, transportation

What services provide realtime (or daily-updated) basic traffic informations for Western Europe ?

For example, [traffic.com/Navteq](http://www.traffic.com) provides such data to Bing Maps for US/Canada and Microsoft suggests [CENTRICO](http://www.centrico.org)/[OTAP](http://www.itsproj.com/otap) for Europe in its documentation (which is outdated, [EasyWay](http://easyway-its.eu) seems to have replaced this service), but its website is slightly confusing.

Are there other major actors in this market for Europe ?

---

For example, [One Step Ahead](http://www.onestepahead.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=101%3areal-time-traffic-information&catid=60%3ashowroom&Itemid=55) seems to provide [free] data for Germany, Netherlands and Belgium, but it's a single file per country (hence not tiled data), and I'm not sure how often it is updated.

Comment: Other than NavTeq, Inrix and Tomtom any other companies that are in the traffic business?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a recent [Navteq press release](http://press.navteq.com/index.php?s=4260&item=25814): "... NAVTEQ Traffic is also currently available in (these) 23 countries around the world: *Austria, Belgium, Brazil, Canada, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Indonesia, Italy, Luxembourg, Mexico, The Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Russia, South Africa, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Arab Emirates, the United Kingdom, United States.*" A number of these cover Western Europe.

As an aside (since I sometimes forget TomTom is no longer partnering with Navteq): [Google maps, and Navteq, which is owned by Nokia, are TomTom's commercial rivals in the digital map-making market.](http://www.forexyard.com/en/news/TomTom-faces-squeeze-from-rivals-free-services-2011-02-18T123025Z-UPDATE-3)

Comment: TomTom bought TeleAtlas hence the non-partnership with NavTeq http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeleAtlas#TomTom_takeover - NavTeq are owned by Nokia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navteq

Answer (score 4):

TeleAtlas now TomTom

http://licensing.tomtom.com/OurProducts/TrafficProducts/index.htm

Enterprise Traffic
Navigate with up-to-the minute information

Multinet Coverage Map (PDF)

http://licensing.tomtom.com/OurProducts/MapData/ssLINK/TA_CT048001